# Validation for 1:m relationship where only one related record can have yes/no field = True

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a fairly standard Access database split into different tables, with data entry done in a series of forms. Everything is working well so far in terms of data validation, functionality/event processes etc.

I have hit one final issue which I feel should be fairly simple to resolve but I'm stuck.

Lets call one of the tables ASSET, which holds property records. Then another table called AGENT, which contains a list of contacts that look after the properties. Then a further table called OWNER, which contains a list of the organisation that owns the ASSET (this is related via the AGENT to avoid duplicate relationships).

Each ASSET has one AGENT, and each AGENT belongs to one OWNER. However, an OWNER can have many AGENTS. We want to identify the principle AGENT (contact) for each OWNER, which is separate to identifying which AGENT is responsible for which ASSET. 
I've therefore included a 'OWNER_PRIMARY_AGENT' yes/no field on the AGENT table. Only one AGENT related to each OWNER should have this ticked. However, I'm not sure how to enforce this in terms of validation/expressions.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation rule to the checkbox with the following expression:

`(DCount("*","Agents","IsPrimary=Yes and OwnerID=" & [OwnerID])+IIf([IsPrimary],1,0))<=1`

Looks pretty heinous but what it does is:

- Count the number of primary agents for this Owner (it assumes there is an OwnerID field on the current form - i.e. the Agent form).
- Adds 1 if the checkbox is checked.
- Ensures that sum is no more than 1.

Add a nice `ValidationText` along with this and it will enforce your rule of only one primary agency per owner.

Edit: Note: this applies the rule to the UI. If you want the rule enforced by the schema you will need to look at data macros. Alternatively, you could add a field on owner that points to the primary agent and not use a flag on agent, but that also requires its own validation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give it a go.